# How to select a div and display another div with more description about that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im new on jquery and nowhere in javascript but anyway im trying to create this carousel where you can click any item from the list and show more infos about that item on the left div.

Here is the preview:
[image: web part screenshot]

I've already created the carousel on the right part but im stuck on what to use for displaying  the left part when specific item is selected can i do it with any jquery plugin or do i need to deep dive in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example

HMTL

```
<div id="slidercontent">      
  <div>Details 1</div>
  <div>Details 2</div>
  <div>Details 3</div>      
</div>

<div id="pager">
  <div>pager 1</div>
  <div>pager 2</div>
  <div>pager 3</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
//Hidding the slidercontent
    $('#slidercontent div').hide();

    //Displaying first slidercontent
    $('#slidercontent div').eq(0).show();


    $('#pager div').click(function(){
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $('#slidercontent div').hide().eq( idx ).fadeTo(500, 1);
        $('#pager div').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
<div id="carousel">

    <div id="details">      
      <div>Details 1</div>
      <div>Details 2</div>
      <div>Details 3</div>      
    </div>

    <div id="info">
      <div>info 1</div>
      <div>info 2</div>
      <div>info 3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/azaper/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $det = $('#details > div');
$det.eq(0).show();

$('#info > div').click(function(){

  var idx = $(this).index();
  $det.hide().eq( idx ).fadeTo(500, 1);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event to the carousel list item, on click, fire an ajax call to your server and retrieve the html or json and display it in the left div.

something like this might work

```
$("#carousel > li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
    //$.post("url.html", { fruit: $(this).attr("value") }, function(data) {
    //    $("#left").html("<span>" + $(this).attr("value") + "</span>" + data);
    //}
});
```

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/qbpuv/)